# How to see System.out for executable jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a little java tool that should make some console output by `System.out.println()`.
But if I export it as runnable jar and run it by `javaw.exe -jar path\to\myfile.jar`, it is executed but there is no output on the console!

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work otherwise, ie is it actually running?

Comment: did you check the .jar actually contains the files you're expecting it to? and the manifest to specify the class that's supposed to be running?

Comment: yes it's actually running. It's a client terminal tool for testing a webservice. I can see at the webserver there is a client connecting. But I cannot see any sysout on the client terminal. After executing the command above, it just "looks as if it was finised" and goes again to c:\users\myself\ and is ready to take new command promts. As if the launched java tool has finished. But it continues to run in background, without terminal out.

Comment: Is it windows? Are you sure it's being launched by java and javaw?

Comment: sorry, yes you're right. It's win7 and I'm running by javaw. I can also run it by doubleclick in the jar, BUT I do not see any terminal poping up...

Comment: You know that javaw doesn't have a console window?

Comment: No I did not... ok. The solution indeed was to use "path\to\java.exe -jar path\to\myfile.jar"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`javaw.exe` does not have a console associated with it. you need to use `java.exe`. If java is not on the path, enter the full path, e.g. `path\to\java.exe -jar path\to\myfile.jar`